# Recreate bootloader fails with 'cannot find EFI directory'

Tags: debian, grub2, boot-loader

I setup debian 9 for a friend of mine. Now I got the laptop back and no bootable media is found on start.

I booted from the usb drive I installed from using the live mode and followed these steps: https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall which led me to here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot

When I execute 12 `grub-install /dev/sdb` I get

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

On sdb1 I got /EFI/debian/grubx64.efi
On sdb2 I got /proc /sys /run etc.

I'm not sure if sdb1 is my boot-partition or not - I tried both skipping/executing 8 `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot`.

I used sdb2 for all other sdXY-commands.

When I execute 13 `update-grub` I get lots of `mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/os-prober/mount': No such file or directory.`

How do I recreate the bootloader?

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: loop0 -> 2G (live), sda (hdd)->sda1 931.5G , sdb (ssd, system)->sdb1 512M, sdb2 19.8G, sdb3 6.9G, sdb4 6.9G, sdb5 1.2G, sdb6 76.5G, sdc -> sdc1 (live) 2.2G, sdc2 416K

Comment: `sdb1` is probably the ESP (EFI System Partition).  You can confirm by checking the partition GUID; it should be `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`

Comment: Yes, it is the EFI-Partition. However I wasn't able to recreate it manually. Boot-repair with separate live-cd didn't work for me `close all package managers` - but I had none open, so I ended up using Rescatux: https://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Answer (score 1):

If `sdb1` contains `/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`, then that is very likely the EFI system partition, and Debian expects it to be already mounted at `/boot/efi` when things like `update-grub` are executed, so that the full path to the Debian bootloader would be `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`.

Depending on choices made at installation time, Debian can have both `/boot` and `/boot/efi` as separate filesystems at the same time. In that case, `/boot/efi` will contain just the `<mountpoint>/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`, and `/boot/grub` (i.e. the `<mountpoint>/grub` directory on the `boot` filesystem) will contain `grub.cfg`, the `x86_64-efi` directory for GRUB modules, and other parts of GRUB.